# Return value when passing a function as an argument in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript code that works fine when I pass an object to a method. In [the API documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/#dsq-login-google), it says that I can also pass a function to the method. When I try this, I'm able to pass parameters and do an alert to verify that the parameters are being passed. However, I'm not able to return the value.

What is the line of javascript that I'm missing to properly return the value?

```
var result = {model: "todo"};

//$httpBackend.whenGET(/^\/api\//).respond(result);
$httpBackend.whenGET(/^\/api\//).respond(do_something);

function do_something(method, url, data) {
    alert("url "+url); // or whatever
    var result =  {model: "todo"};
    return result;
}

//From the API documentation
//   $httpBackend.whenGET('/.*/').respond(function(method, url, data) {
//     do something
//});
```

Comment: Which API are you using?

Comment: The value is returned to whatever calls the function `do_something`. It's not your code, it's whatever is inside `.respond`. If that function does not return the value of your callback (which is likely because it seems to be an asynchronous call), then you cannot get the return value.

Comment: The call $httpBackend.whenGET(/^\/api\//).respond(result); works properly.

Comment: I am using this API. http://docs.angularjs.org/#dsq-login-google.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the return value of that function is ignored.  Certainly it's not being used in your current code.

You need to have that function affect a variable scoped outside of the function itself:

```
var result;
$httpBackend.whenGET(/^\/api\//).respond(do_something);
// Do something with `result`...
alert(result.model); // or whatever

function do_something(method, url, data) {
    alert("url "+url); // or whatever
    result =  {model: "todo"};
}
```

Comment: This only works if `$httpBackend.whenGET(/^\/api\//).respond(do_something);` is synchronous (which does not look like to be the case but I don't know the API).

Comment: @FelixKling: A fair observation.  I hope the OP will fill us in on that missing detail.